# CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure doesn't work

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following fluent validation:

```
RuleFor(o => o.zipCode)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must((o, zipCode) => CountryInfoMap.IsValidPostalCode(zipCode, "AT"))
    .When(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ZipCode))
    .WithMessage(ErrorDto.ToModelMessage(ErrorCode.InvalidZipCode, $"{{PropertyName}} '{{PropertyValue}}' is invalid for specified country."));
```

When no `zipCode` value is passed it still calls the method `CountryInfoMap.IsValidPostalCode` which is a static method. Why doesn't it stop on first failure of it being empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `When`:

```
RuleFor(o => o.zipCode)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must((o, zipCode) => CountryInfoMap.IsValidPostalCode(zipCode, "AT"))
    .WithMessage(ErrorDto.ToModelMessage(ErrorCode.InvalidZipCode, $"{{PropertyName}} '{{PropertyValue}}' is invalid for specified country."));
```

you are already validating it, for it not being empty.